# Custom splash screen on 7" screen with raspberry cm4 not full scale

Tags: compute-module-4

I have a 7" hdmi display attached to my cm4 with ioboard.

everything works fine only cant get the splash screen to use the full screen. Im using FBI.

splashscreen.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Splash screen
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fbi --noverbose -a /usr/bin/display/imgs/splash.png
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

been testing things with overscan etc in config.txt, also tried the fbi zoom arg and -a. Makes no difference at all.

So far nothing works, the splashscreen does show, but just not using the fullscreen.

Ive been trying multiple changes to configs, but it hasnt been getting any better.

i forced the resolution, i also made sure the splashscreen is the same resolution as the screen.